# Groovy replaceAll Comma

Tags: csv, groovy, replaceall

I'm having issues with the replaceAll feature in Groovy.
I'm working on a CSV parser assignment, and I'm trying to replace commas with spaces.  I cannot figure out the syntax to actually replace them, as every time I run the script the data is returned with the commas still included.

```
class ActAsCSV {
    def headers = []
    def contents = []     
    def read() {
        def file = new File('C:/Users/Alex/Desktop/csv.txt')
        def lines = file.readLines()
        headers = lines[0].split(",")

        def last = lines.tail()
        def i = 0
        while (last[i] != null){last[i].replaceAll(/,(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)/' ')
           println last[i]
           i++}
        }    
}

alex = new ActAsCSV()
alex.read()
```

The CSV file looks like this:
    Year,Make,Model

```
1997,Ford,E350

2000,Mercury,Cougar
```

The headers array works as it is supposed to.  The output after the current code is

```
1997,Ford,E350
2000,Mercury,Cougar
```

I have tried

","

','

/','/

/,/

and various regexp patterns I have found online. Literally nothing has worked.  I don't know what I am missing, I assumed replaceAll wouldn't be this hard.  I have looked over the documentation, but am unsure how to apply a string, closure combo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the `replaceAll()` method returns the resulting string, whereas the code above falsely assumes that last[i] is being modified.

That said, consider this code fragment:

```
String tmp = last[i].replaceAll(/,/,' ')
println tmp
```

This will help.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know how I missed that.